# Script not loading in joomla template

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I'm trying to use jquery to display content on my joomla website based on date.  Here is the jsfiddle that is working: http://jsfiddle.net/2BHLd/968/

```
$(function() {
$(".DateDiv").each(function(index) {
    var sRange = $(this).find(".DateRange").html();
    var arrTemp = sRange.split(" to ");
    var dtFrom = new Date(arrTemp[0]);
    var dtTo = new Date(arrTemp[1]);
    var dtNow = new Date();
    if (dtNow >= dtFrom && dtNow <= dtTo)
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

I'm using Jumi to insert the script and css into my page and putting the html into an article.  The CSS seems to be working just fine, as it has hidden the html, but for some reason, the script doesn't appear to be showing the text even if the current date is within the date range.

http://askc.org/galacticos/index.php/events/upcoming-events

This joomla template seems to limit what I can do, but I'm thinking I've just made a simple mistake somewhere and I've spent two hours trying to fix it to no avail. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you using your Jumi code? Jumi lets you add code in three places: linked as a menu item, as a module item, or as a shortcode in an article. Which one are you using?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I have a jumi module pointing to a .js file with a set position, then I'm loading the position in the article.  I've actually used this same approach with several other scripts around the site with no issues.  The CSS that hides the text to begin with is also in the file, so I know that it's at least seeing that.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$` to reference jQuery, while Joomla reserves that for mootools for legacy reasons.

Simply replace *every* occurrence of `$` with `jQuery` so the above code will look like:

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery(".DateDiv").each(function(index) {
    var sRange = jQuery(this).find(".DateRange").html();
    var arrTemp = sRange.split(" to ");
    var dtFrom = new Date(arrTemp[0]);
    var dtTo = new Date(arrTemp[1]);
    var dtNow = new Date();
    if (dtNow >= dtFrom && dtNow <= dtTo)
        jQuery(this).show();
    });
});
```

As an alternative, if you really like having the $ prefix, you could reassign it with

```
$ = jQuery;
```

just before your script; but this could break other functionality that relies on $ being mootools, and it's not the Joomla preferred way of doing it.

Finally, your code is not very resistant,

```
var dtTo = new Date(arrTemp[1]);
```

will break if `sRange` does not contain at least two items, and the following comparison will produce unpredictable results if the `arrTemp` items cannot be converted to dates.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfected, didn't know how Joomla treated the $.  I like the first option best.  Appreciate the notes on the code as well.